# Mysql insert statement and passing parameters to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am trying to execute various statements/queries in my PHP file, depending on what variables are received (moreover, is there a way to send variables and choose what kind of query I want to do, as opposed to making one query for each set of variables received? This is my first time writing in PHP so please forgive the possible stupid question).

In this case its a Username, Password, and UserID. I'd like an insert to occur when these 3 variables are received. However, I keep on receiving an error: java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: GET (this is when conn.setDoOutput isset to true). If I have it set to false, I get a IO URL error which states my URL cannot be found. What am I doing wrong? Below are both my php script and the java code used for GET requests.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("logindetailsgohere");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_GET['Username']) && isset($_Get['Password']) && isset($_GET['UserID'])){
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Password']);
$uid = intval($_GET['UserID']);
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Users (id, Username, Password) VALUES ('$uid', '$uname', '$pass')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql){
    echo "Values have been inserted";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Java code:

```
public String connect() {

    try {
        /*URL url = new URL("phpfilelocation.php");*/
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("un", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(un, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pw, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("uid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(uid), "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("phpfilelocation.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your request String to see if URLEncoder is actually encoding correctly? I experienced some weird behavior with it in the past and had to add some additional methods to ensure proper encoding.

Comment: `wr.write(data); - that's (part of) what URLConnection is complaining about. Make up your mind: either GET (and appending data directly to the url string) or POST (and writing data in the request body/output stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this PHP script does an INSERT statement, it's strongly recommended that you use POST parameters.

Java code:

```
public String connect() {

    try {
    /*URL url = new URL("phpfilelocation.php");*/
        String data = "&" + URLEncoder.encode("un", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(un, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pw, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("uid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(uid), "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("phpfilelocation.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("logindetailsgohere");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['un']) && isset($_POST['pw']) && isset($_POST['uid'])){
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['un']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pw']);
$uid = intval($_POST['uid']);
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Users (id, Username, Password) VALUES ('$uid', '$uname', '$pass')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql){
    echo "Values have been inserted";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As an aside, for a GET request, you just append the parameters to the end of the url when you create the `URL` object.

```
public String connect() {

    try {
    /*URL url = new URL("phpfilelocation.php");*/
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("un", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(un, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pw, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("uid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(uid), "UTF-8");

        String urlString = "phpfilelocation.php" + "?" + data;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        //remove:
        //OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        //wr.write(data);
        //wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

Comment: But ...in the php script the (only visible) action is an sql INSERT. If that's also the "purpose" from the client's perspective the request should be made via POST.

Comment: @VolkerK Very very true.  I'll update to show how to do it with POST as well.

Answer (score 0):

PHP :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users(id, UserName, Password)
VALUES ('$uid', '$uname', '$pass')");
```

JAVA :

```
String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
String unameDB="username";
String passDB="password";
Class.forName(driver);
Connection c=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,unameDB,passDB);
Statement s=c.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `Users`(ID,UserName,Password) VALUE ('"+uid+"','"+uname+"','"+pass+"')");
```