# PHP, MySQL and AJAX: Storing selected elements in a database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have multiple elements with checkboxes; on selecting a box, I want to store some of its attributes passed via the ajax data parameter into a database table. Here's an example of the JS and html markup.

```js
$("input[type="submit"]").live("change", function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'fetch.php',
            data:
                {
                    id: $(this).attr('id'),
                    checked: 'yes'
                }
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<li>
  <label for="one"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one">
</li>
<li>
  <label for="two"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
</li>
<li>
  <label for="three"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three">
</li>
```

However, as a PHP and mysql newbie, after succesfully connecting to my mysql table, I got stuck on the actual PHP code. The following doesn't do anything and I'm struggling to proceed.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['id'])) {
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $value){
      $query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ". $value. ";";
      mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
  } else {
      echo "nothing checked";
  }
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your checkboxs don't have a value set in HTML

Comment: It looks like $_POST['id'] will never be an array because each time you click a checkbox it sends exactly one id field.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You should use `.on()` for event delegation.

Comment: Use `$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {`

Comment: I don't think the `change` event fires on submit buttons. You should be using `click`. And submit buttons can't be checked.

Comment: That should be `$("#formid").on("click", ":checkbox", function() { ... })`

Comment: @Barmar, yes or some such, I was editing my comment as you added yours, the "submit" point remains valid, no form to submit here in the OP post...can/should we assume that? Not sure.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss My comment was intended for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` query is not well formated.

Try something like this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (column_name) VALUES ('". $value. "')";
```

**Important note** : Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and may compromise the security of your database. You should use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/mysqli) APIs to secure your SQL queries, and using [`prepare`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) function.

Comment: Don't do that, use parameters for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167924/c-sharp-with-mysql-insert-parameters

Comment: Thanks; does the ajax and the rest of the PHP look correct to you?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I warn O.P. of the dangers of non-prepared queries. Thanks.

Comment: @IsaaK08 Please read the **important note** in the anwser.

Comment: Another example for the OP https://stackoverflow.com/a/31149701/125981

Comment: @Syscall, yes, just making it painfully obvious to the OP hence the comment/examples.

Comment: @IsaaK08 The rest of the PHP is wrong. `$_POST['id']` is not an array, so you shouldn't use a `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @Barmar realized my mistakes. Thanks!